# glyphicons not showing with sass bootstrap integration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, fonts, sass, laravel-elixir

I used this tutorial to integrate bootstrap in my project:

https://laravel-news.com/2015/10/setup-bootstrap-sass-with-laravel-elixir/

This places an app.css file in the css folder.
However if I try to use glyphicons they don't show up.
So I tried to modify the elixir file like this:

```
    elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass('app.scss')
        .browserify('app.js')
        .copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts', 'public/css/fonts')   

});
```

The fonts folder is copied under public/css/fonts but yet no icon shows up. What am I missing here? Any clue?

in my app.css the path seems correct, for example:

```
src: url("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing up, when you call the <code>gulp</code> command in the terminal?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem with fresh install of laravel 5.2. 
What I did is just inspected the request path in browser which was :

```
../build/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

so I just added to gulp.js this :

```
mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/','public/build/fonts/bootstrap');
```

and afterwards in terminal :

```
gulp
```

That did the trick for me!

Comment: worked for me by removing `build` from the target path

Comment: Didn't work for me. Using Laravel 5.3 and modified gulpfile.js

Comment: @BasilMusa Laravel 5.3 remove build dir

Comment: mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', 'public/fonts/bootstrap');    @BasilMusa

Answer (score 8):

You should in your `app.scss` **before** including bootstrap file set variable `$icon-font-path` value correctly, probably in your case it should be:

```
$icon-font-path: '/css/fonts/';
```

Comment: @Chriz74 So where your font actually are In `public/css/fonts` or in `public/css/fonts/bootstrap`? If in the second one try changing if with valid path.

Comment: Second one, bootstrap

Comment: So try with `$icon-font-path: '/css/fonts/bootstrap/'; at the same beginning of your `app.scss` file

Comment: error was here: I was trying with `<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-ok"></span>` instead of `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>`

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me in Laravel 5.3 on Windows

1. First make sure you are using the NodeJS package latest version (v6.7.0)

   Click the tab **"Current Latest Features"** at the URL https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
2. Run `npm install`
3. Modify the file `gulpfile.js` to contain the following:

   ```
   elixir(mix => {
       mix.sass('app.scss')
          .webpack('app.js');
       mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/','public/fonts/bootstrap');
   });
   ```
4. Run gulp:

   ```
   gulp
   ```
5. Thats it.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.4, just install npm dependencies and run npm in production or dev as needed.

```
npm install
npm run production
```

Laravel will do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.4 what I did is

```
mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', 'public/fonts/bootstrap');
```

And in `resources/assets/sass/_variables.scss` or `app.scss`

```
$icon-font-path: '/fonts/bootstrap/';
```

Comment: I use Laravel 5.4, icons doesn't work. I checked my `app.css` file and saw that font's path is `/fonts/`. When I manually edit this path to `../fonts` instead of `/fonts` it works. I can not figure out how to make this path. I can't change `$icon-font-path' to `../fonts`, it gives me an error.

Comment: Hi! Make sure your font folder is in `public` directory and to modify your path it should go like this.

`$icon-font-path: '/fonts/';`

note: you have to edit it on `resources/assets/sass/`

Comment: It was in public. I fixed. I changed publicPath in 'webconfig.mix.js' file.  Set publicPath for fonts to '../'

Comment: In a clean install of Laravel 5.4 you simply have to do `npm install` and `npm run dev`; the default Laravel setup is already correct.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.3 remove build

```
mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', 'public/fonts/bootstrap');
```

run gulp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Laravel 5.4 It turns out that I hadn't run `npm install` and `npm run dev`.

Once these two commands were run, the fonts (and glyphicons) were copied correctly into the /public directory. There was no need to edit any sass or build files.

Answer (score 1):

### For Laravel 5.4

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795847/glyphicons-not-showing-with-sass-bootstrap-integration/39850165#39850165) answer didn't exactly solved my problem but it pointed me to the right direction. This is my solution and it covers both if you have defined url for your application (using homestead or some other VM/Vagrant/etc. or if you have set vhost and hosts file for your application), or if you're like me, and have installed lamp stack/xampp/wamp/mapm/etc and doing development from apache htdocs sbfolder.

Firstly you need to add
`mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', 'public/fonts/');`
in your `webpack.mix.js` at the end of the file.

Next open up `resources/assets/sass/_variable.scss` and edit `$icon-font-path` value.

If you're not using homestead but some lamp stack where you don't have defined dev url for your application (you didn't set vhost and changed hosts file), but instead you're accessing it as a subfolder e.g. `localhost/YOUR_APP/public/` then you should set icon font path like
`$icon-font-path: "/YOUR_APP/public/fonts/";`

If you have set url for your application, you just need to set icon font paht like
`$icon-font-path: "/public/fonts/"` and recompile css file. ***You should change to this before pushing your application to the production if it's not set at first!!!***

For those who don't know how to recompile css and js files follow this steps:
1. Go to the root of your application and run bash there (git bash, cmd, etc.)
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run-script production` (you have other flags available but i perfer production as it minifies js and css)
4. Congrats you just recompiled your js and css

Answer (score 0):

If you are using elixir() helper in your blade templates, you should put your fonts files into /public/build. As result /public/build/fonts, the "fonts" folder contains all font files.

Answer (score 0):

- Look into developer tools of your browser watch the path.
- In mine, it was public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf I downloaded those fonts manually placed them there.
- And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In webpack.config.js set:

```bash
publicPath: '../'
```

Instead of 
Mix.resourceRoot

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap4 doesn't come with icons anymore [bootstrap icons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/extend/icons/)

you can use Font Awesome instead for example.

Build your webpack.mix.js configuration.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Install Font Awesome.

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

In /resources/sass/app.scss import one or more styles.

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

now compile.

```
npm run production
or
npm run dev
```

Finally, reference your new CSS file in your layout.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer, I have this implemented now in a much better way, similar to the top answer.  In app.scss:

```
/* BOOTSTRAP */
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

/* FONT-AWESOME */
$fa-font-path: "../../fonts";
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Comment: @Chriz74 because my CSS file is in `build` when I mix it with elixir.  So when that file references fonts, they are relative to the `build` folder, not the `public` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
   gulp.src('.node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/fonts/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg,woff2}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/fonts'));
});
```

and then add

```
mix
//other scripts
.task('fonts')
```

Comment: thanks but it was working already, error was here: I was trying with `<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-ok"></span>` instead of `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>`