# Laravel Glyphicons not showing

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, glyphicons

The Laravel application is not showing the glyphicons, because is shown the error "***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)***"?

**Solution:**

> $ mkdir public/css/fonts
>
> $ cp
>   node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
>   public/css/fonts/
>
> $ cp
>   node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
>   public/css/fonts/
>
> $ cp
>   node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>   public/css/fonts/

Comment: Which file specifically is 404?

Comment: I had  similar problem. In Laravel 5.4 (in my case) gluphicons are not loading. I wrote a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367436/2080604) for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, resolved this with adding

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: works for me, I downloaded this file and used locally later

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

```
public_path()
```

function provided by Laravel, it'll handle getting the public path correctly on development and production.

If you're pulling in through a blade file, try

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src:url({{public_path() . '/css/fonts/<<nameOfFileHere>>'}});
}
```

Or you could use a CDN if having it locally isn't fully required.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons weren't working for me on laravel 7 and I found this article very useful. It explains how to add Glyphicons for laravel in very simple manner.

[How to use Glyphicons with a Laravel project](https://projecthn.000webhostapp.com/article/7)

But I had to do a small change for get this working.

```
$icon-font-path: '../fonts/bootstrap/';
```

to

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
```

Comment: It's a dead link :(

Comment: @Heichou As I remember the issue happens due to the removal of glyphicons from bootstrap 4. You can either use bootstrap 3 instead (Via CDN or NPM) or can use fontawesome library

Comment: Yes I did with fontawesome!